# Django filter model by method result

Tags: django, django-models, django-filter

I'm looking to filter a model (InventoryItem) by a custom defined method (current_location) that is the filtered queryset of another model (InventoryMovement). I've tried reading the Django documentation, but can't make out exactly how they are using model managers to achieve something like this.

One example of what I'm trying to achieve would be something like:

```
InventoryItem.objects.filter(current_warehouse='A')
```

Code is:

```
class InventoryAddress:
    def __init__(self, warehouse, location, sublocation):
        self.warehouse = warehouse
        self.location = location
        self.sublocation = sublocation

class InventoryItem(models.Model):
    inventory_sku = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, primary_key=True, null=False, blank=False,
                                     verbose_name="Inventory SKU")
    authenticated = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=yes_no_choices, verbose_name='Authentication Status')

    # GenericForeignKey for Specific Product
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    object_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def movements(self):
        movements = InventoryMovement.objects.filter(inventory_item=self)
        return sorted(movements, key=lambda x: x.datetime_entered, reverse=True)

    def completed_movements(self):
        movements = InventoryMovement.objects.filter(inventory_item=self, datetime_completed__isnull=False)
        return sorted(movements, key=lambda x: x.datetime_completed, reverse=True)

    def current_location(self):
        movements = self.completed_movements()
        if movements:
            last_movement = movements[0]
            loc = InventoryAddress(
                warehouse=last_movement.warehouse,
                location=last_movement.location,
                sublocation=last_movement.sublocation
            )
        else:
            loc = InventoryAddress(
                warehouse='EXT',
                location=None,
                sublocation=None,
            )
        return loc

    def current_warehouse(self):
        return self.current_location().warehouse


class InventoryMovement(models.Model):
    movement_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='Movement ID')
    warehouse = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False, blank=False, choices=warehouse_location_choices,
                                 verbose_name='Warehouse')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Target Bin')
    sublocation = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Target Position')
    inventory_item = models.ForeignKey(InventoryItem, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                       verbose_name="Inventory Item")
```

Comment: Could you explain more specifically your problem? We don't know which attributes will filter the `InventoryItem`s and what do you actually mean by "(current_location) that is the filtered queryset of another model (InventoryMovement). " ?

Comment: So I would like to filter for any InventoryItem where the current_location().warehouse is 'A'. current_location() is the first InventoryMovement object found in the sorted (by date_completed) queryset of InvenotryMovment.objects.filter(inventory_item=x) where x is a given InventoryItem object. Since current_location isn't stored as state in the InventoryItem object and instead is calculated via the current_location method (of InvenotryItem), I'm not sure how to go about filtering for that